# In javascript can I use something like if( val = sum(2,3))?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, boolean-logic

In JavaScript when is it correct and cross-browser to use.

```
function sum(v1,v2) { return v1+v2;}

...

if(val = sum(1,2)) alert(val);
else alert('result zero or null');

...
```

Comment: Why don't you just try it? Most browsers have JavaScript consoles where you can execute code...

Comment: Whether you *should* do it is another question. The meaning is not intuitive (imo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Of course you can. It works in many(or some - at least it doesn't work in Python) program languages like PHP.

That's why many programming beginners have trouble with `=` and `==`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes.  OK.  I've reached the character minimum.

But make sure that you do double equals signs: `if ( x == y)....`

Answer (score 0):

I believe there was one version of JavaScript (1.2 perhaps?) where `if (x = y)` would be corrected to `if (x == y)`.